# Excessive downvoting

Tags: support

At the moment about 6 questions on the front page are down-voted,
it was not like that about 10 minutes ago - seems there is just one user who creates a series of downvotes.

It seems to me that it is absolutely inappropriate behavior.

How to ask stackoverflow team to react on that ?

PS

Conflict of interest: [my own question](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/84240/loading-collections-of-datasets-python-code-examples) has been also downvoted, but you see it is not only happens with me.

Comment: are you concerned about the number of downvotes or the reasons for the downvotes? if the votes are unjustified it would be a different problem. also, some behaviors like [serial downvoting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me) are caught by the system and automatically reversed.

Answer (score 3):

Not really an answer, rather a general explanation:

Quite often I see downvotes that I disagree with on DataScienceSE. When it happens I just upvote (did so on your question).

I suspect that this is a consequence of the rather vague scope of the site: some people may consider a strict definition of data science (e.g. only ML-related questions), some may expect a very specific and well thought out question, etc. I don't blame the downvoters, if one honestly considers that a question is not good enough (and it's true that we see many low quality question on DSSE) they should indeed "vote early vote often", as the recommendation goes.

In my humble opinion the main issue is that unfortunately we are too few regular voters on DSSE: normally on SE the number of votes is supposed to balance things out, i.e. statistically a good question is supposed to converge to a good score eventually. But the average number of votes on DSSE is probably around 1 or 2 these days, and as everyone here knows you can't have a good sample with 1 or 2 points.

Conclusion: I think the problem on DSSE is not about the downvoters, at least they try to contribute, the problem is the lack of upvoters ;)